# Как изменить курсор между виджетами QSplitter?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlayout, pyside6, qsplitter

Мне очень подошёл способ объединение виджетов, через `QSplitter`, т.к. в нём я могу настроить расстояние между виджетами.

Я чуть позже объединяю `QLayout` и `QSplitter`. Так вот, пространство между виджетами (`QPushButton`) имеет определённый курсор.

На скрине курсор не сохраняется, мне хотелось бы его изменить. 
Позже добавлю для кнопок изображения.

Если есть замечания по коду, пожалуйста расскажите. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QMessageBox, QDialog,
    QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QSplitter, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QSizePolicy)
from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt)

class change_word(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet(u'background-color: rgb(56, 56 ,56)')

        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.VLayout_buttons = QSplitter()
        self.VLayout_buttons.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)
        self.VLayout_buttons.setOpaqueResize(True)
        self.VLayout_buttons.setHandleWidth(20)
        self.VLayout_buttons.setChildrenCollapsible(True)

        self.VLayout_word = QVBoxLayout()
        self.HLayout_all = QHBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        self.sizePolicy_button = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Maximum, QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        self.button_change = QPushButton()
        self.button_change.setMinimumSize(40, 40)
        self.button_change.setSizePolicy(self.sizePolicy_button)

        self.button_delete = QPushButton()
        self.button_delete.setMinimumSize(40, 40)
        self.button_delete.setSizePolicy(self.sizePolicy_button)

        self.VLayout_buttons.addWidget(self.button_change)
        self.VLayout_buttons.addWidget(self.button_delete)

        self.Filter_line = QLineEdit(self.central_widget)
        self.Filter_line.setStyleSheet(
            'color: white;'
            'background: rgb(80, 80, 80);'
            'border: 2px solid rgb(90, 90, 90);'
            'border-radius: 3px'
        )
        self.Filter_line.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.search_func(self.Filter_line.text()))

        self.List_Word = QListWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.List_Word.setStyleSheet(
            'QListWidget {'
            'background: rgb(80, 80, 80);'
            'color: White;'
            'font-size: 14px'
            '}'
            'QListWidget::item:hover {'
            'background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 40)'
            '}'
            'QListWidget::item:selected {'
            'background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 70)'
            '}'
        )
        self.List_Word.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.Double_clicked_item)
        Words = ['Crash', 'Smash', 'Trouble', 'Error', 'Smile']
        self.List_Word.addItems(Words)

        self.VLayout_word.addWidget(self.Filter_line)
        self.VLayout_word.addWidget(self.List_Word)

        self.HLayout_all.addLayout(self.VLayout_word)
        self.HLayout_all.addWidget(self.VLayout_buttons)


    def search_func(self, sort_filter):
        for index in range(self.List_Word.count()):
            item = self.List_Word.item(index)
            if sort_filter.lower() in item.text().lower():
                item.setHidden(False)
            else:
                item.setHidden(True)

    def Double_clicked_item(self, item: QListWidgetItem):
        print(item.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = change_word()
    size = main_win.screen().availableSize()
    main_win.resize(size.width()/4, size.height()/2)
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QSplitterHandle *[**QSplitter::handle(int index)**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsplitter.html#handle) const
>
> Возвращает дескриптор слева (или выше) элемента в макете разделителя по заданному индексу или nullptr, если такого элемента нет. 
> Дескриптор с индексом 0 всегда скрыт.

---

Некоторые несвязанные, но все же важные предложения:

1. имена классов и констант всегда должны быть написаны с заглавной буквы,
   а функции и переменные всегда должны начинаться со строчной буквы;
2. всегда должна быть пустая строка между функциями и две для разделения классов;
3. всегда ставьте пробелы вокруг символа равенства, используемого для присваивания;
4. ...

Не стоит недооценивать все эти аспекты, так как они очень важны для удобочитаемости
(что очень важно).
Вы можете прочитать больше в официальном [**Руководстве по стилю для кода Python**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

---

```
import sys
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, 
    QWidget, QMessageBox, QDialog, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, 
    QSplitter, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QSizePolicy)
from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt)
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

# --> v.....v... <-----------------------------------------------------
class ChangeWord(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet(u'background-color: rgb(56, 56 ,56)')

        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
# ----------> vvvvvvvv <--------------------------------------------------
#        self.splitter = QSplitter()
        self.VLayout_buttons = QSplitter()
        self.VLayout_buttons.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)
        self.VLayout_buttons.setOpaqueResize(True)
        self.VLayout_buttons.setHandleWidth(20)                       # ? 20
        self.VLayout_buttons.setChildrenCollapsible(True)

# ----------> VvV.......... <--------------------------------------------------
#        self.v_layout_word = QVBoxLayout()        
        self.VLayout_word = QVBoxLayout()
        self.HLayout_all = QHBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        self.sizePolicy_button = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Maximum, QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        self.button_change = QPushButton()
        self.button_change.setMinimumSize(40, 40)
        self.button_change.setSizePolicy(self.sizePolicy_button)

        self.button_delete = QPushButton()
        self.button_delete.setMinimumSize(40, 40)
        self.button_delete.setSizePolicy(self.sizePolicy_button)

        self.VLayout_buttons.addWidget(self.button_change)
        self.VLayout_buttons.addWidget(self.button_delete)

        self.Filter_line = QLineEdit(self.central_widget)
        self.Filter_line.setStyleSheet(
            'color: white;'
            'background: rgb(80, 80, 80);'
            'border: 2px solid rgb(90, 90, 90);'
            'border-radius: 3px'
        )
        self.Filter_line.textChanged.connect(self.search_func)
# ???            lambda: self.search_func(self.Filter_line.text()))

        self.List_Word = QListWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.List_Word.setStyleSheet(
            'QListWidget {'
            'background: rgb(80, 80, 80);'
            'color: White;'
            'font-size: 14px'
            '}'
            'QListWidget::item:hover {'
            'background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 40)'
            '}'
            'QListWidget::item:selected {'
            'background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 70)'
            '}'
        )
        self.List_Word.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.Double_clicked_item)
        Words = ['Crash', 'Smash', 'Trouble', 'Error', 'Smile']
        self.List_Word.addItems(Words)

        self.VLayout_word.addWidget(self.Filter_line)
        self.VLayout_word.addWidget(self.List_Word)

        self.HLayout_all.addLayout(self.VLayout_word)
        self.HLayout_all.addWidget(self.VLayout_buttons)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('_+_.png').scaled(80, 80) 
        cursor = QtGui.QCursor(pixmap)        
        self.handle = self.VLayout_buttons.handle(1)
        self.handle.setCursor(cursor)         
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def search_func(self, sort_filter):
        for index in range(self.List_Word.count()):
            item = self.List_Word.item(index)
            if sort_filter.lower() in item.text().lower():
                item.setHidden(False)
            else:
                item.setHidden(True)

    def Double_clicked_item(self, item: QListWidgetItem):
        print(item.text())
         
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
QSS = """
QSplitter::handle {
    background: #DAA520;
}
QSplitter::handle:pressed {
    background: #FFD700;
}
"""
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)                                            # +++
    
    main_win = ChangeWord()
    size = main_win.screen().availableSize()
    main_win.resize(size.width()/4, size.height()/2)
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**`_+_.png`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @PeFoo что не так?

Comment: Благодарю что поправили и ответили, теперь благодаря вам знаю как поставить картинку на курсор XD ) и теперь станет лучше грамматика года =). Только почему то упоминаю ваше имя и оно пропадает из текста, всё делаю правильно ._.

Comment: извиняюсь что трачу ваше время, но у меня есть один вопрос, почему курсор меняется если мы не применяем метод SetCursor непосредственно к self.VLayout_buttons ?

Comment: @PeFoo пожалуйста. Если у вас есть другие проблем, задайте новый вопрос, приведите ваш код, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: пока проблем не появилось ), просто непонятен фрагмент кода, а так я вам очень благодарен )